# Parse Server Mailgun not Sending Emails

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, mailgun, forgot-password

I'm trying to use the mailgun adapter to send password reset emails to my user, however I'm unable to send the email. On the client side I'm calling:

```
[PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded) {
                NSLog(@"success");
            }else{
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
            }

        }];
```

And here is my code in index.js:

```
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-mailgun',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'Natch Support <mailgun@x.co>',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'mg.x.co',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      templates: {
        passwordResetEmail: {
          subject: 'Reset your password',
          pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, '/public/Change_Password.txt'),
          pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, '/public/choose_password.html'),
          callback: (user) => { return { firstName: user.get('firstName') }}
          // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates
         },
        verificationEmail: {
          subject: 'Confirm your account',
          pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, '/public/verification_email.txt'),
          pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, '/public/verification_email.html'),
          callback: (user) => { return { firstName: user.get('firstName') }}
          // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates
        },
        customEmailAlert: {
          subject: 'Urgent notification!',
          pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, '/public/templates/custom_alert.txt'),
          pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, '/public/templates/custom_alert.html'),
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I can send emails via the Mailgun API and other methods listed in the quickstart guide. But I cannot get the emails to send from iOS. I'm only interested in sending the password reset emails. If you have any suggestions I'd love to hear them. Thank you!